# Specification of nextInt (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wrote follow code. I thought when I use the number is less than 6,it will enter an infinite loop because \n is not erased by scanner.nextLine(). But this code can run without any problem. why is this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
　Scanner scannner = new Scanner(System.in)

  int num = 0
  
  boolean isValid = false;
  while(!isValid){
    try{
       System.out.print("please input number:")
       inputedNum = scanner.nextInt()
       
       if(inputedNum < 6){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("please input number more than 6")
       }
       
       isValid = true

     }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage())
     }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("please input number")
        scanner.nextLine()
     }
  }

}
```

I think this code will enter an infinite loop because \n is not erased by scanner.nextLine() If inputedNum < 6

Comment: `nextInt()` can read past newlines. Infinite loops only happen when `nextInt()` itself throws an error, because the token is not consumed.

Answer (score 2):

The `\n` character doesn't affect `nextInt` in this case. `nextInt` would just skip over `\n` when looking for the next integer in the input. Therefore, it would successfully scan the next integer you enter. If that is less than 6, `isValid` would be set to true, and there is no infinite loop.

This is because by default, `\n` is included in the [`delimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter()) of a `Scanner`. Scanner considers strings that match its delimiters as "separators" of the tokens it scans.

```
System.out.println(scanner.delimiter());
// prints "\p{javaWhitespace}+", which would match "\n"
```

---

Even if the scanner scans the `\n` character and tries to interpret it as an int, it would throw an `InputMismatchException`, which would be caught by your second `catch`. Then, the `\n` character would be consumed by `nextLine` anyway. So again, this would not cause an infinite loop, though the output would be a little different.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. I understood! In shot , nextInt() skips \n so infinite loop won't happen , right?